# How to deploy on AWS Amplify (React App)?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy on AWS Amplify. I understand why its not working because it is looking in the wrong folder but I don't know how to change the folder so that it can locate the 'package.json' file. This is what my build settings are..am I missing something?

[Build Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaHTx.png)

Answer (score 0):

To find the root directory, you do not need to cd into a folder.

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```